# Set Content-Type in ASP.net Web Service

Tags: asp.net, xml, soap, asmx, mime

I am working with a partner organization who is sending exports to us utilizing SOAP 1.1 (SOAP with Attachments) with MIME attachments.

The requests are using:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; type=text/xml; start="<start.xml>"; boundary="--MIME_boundary"
```

By default my Service is expecting text/xml since it is using SOAP 1.1.

Can I configure ASP.net Web Services to accept multipart/related content-type programmatically?
Do I need to override things prior to that to set the expected Content-Type?
Do I need to change it at the IIS level (not ideal)?

Here is an example of the type of request I am receiving:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; type=text/xml; start="<start.xml>"; boundary="--MIME_boundary"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
SOAPAction: "ExampleAction"
Authorization: Basic EgaghKD946kszoptTK9ld29gjkkfn4INna


----MIME_boundary
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Id: <start.xml>


<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
  <soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  >
    <soap:Body>
      <DOC>
         <INFO transactionId="0123ABC">
            <ATTACHMENTS>
               <ATTACHMENT
                  href="cid:26541@test.com"
               />
            </ATTACHMENTS>
         </_INFO>
      </DOC>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

----MIME_boundary
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="DOC.ZIP"
Content-Id: <26541@test.com>

** ENCODED DATA **

----MIME_boundary--
```